# How to Get all opened AutoCad documents(drawings) using .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, autocad, autodesk, objectarx

I am using AutoCAD 2012 and the .NET API. Can someone help me how can i loop through the document objects of all the open documents? i am trying to do something like the code below..I have this question on Autodesk Forum too..but not sure how much active it is :)

```
public void GetDocNames()
        {
            DocumentCollection docs = Application.DocumentManager;

            for (int i = 0; i < docs.Count; i++)
            {
                AcadDocument doc = docs[i];
                Debug.Print(doc.Name);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have tagged both C# and VB.NET. The C# version is as follows:

```
public void GetDocNames()
{
  DocumentCollection docs = Application.DocumentManager;

  foreach (Document doc in docs)
  {
    Application.ShowAlertDialog(doc.Name);
  }
}
```

Comment: so if i want to activate the third document, i have to loop all docs in this foreach loop? In the VBA days, we could do it with Documents(2).Activate

Comment: @vinayan I'm not aware of a way to extract a single document from the middle of the collection. Perhaps you could give a bit more detail about the operation you are performing? If you are only performing it on one document then you can select it in AutoCAD and use `DocumentCollection.MdiActiveDocument` to return the correct document from the collection.

Comment: i am trying to get the user to pick an entity from one drawing..then the program will automatically switch to the other drawing and prompt the user to pick one entity from that drawing..the geometry of the first object will be replaced by the second object..thanks for the answer..i think i can still do it by looping..

Comment: Use Linq for that: `Document document = Application.DocumentManager.OfType<Document>().ToArray()[2];`

Answer (score 2):

The VB.NET version:

```vb
Private Sub getAcadDocNames()
    'collection of all opened documents
    Dim AcadDocs As DocumentCollection = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager 

    For Each doc As Document In AcadDocs
        Debug.Print(doc.Name)
    Next doc
End Sub
```

Note that you may want to fully qualify the path of the DocumentManager property (as I've done here) if you've also imported `System.Windows.Forms` (which also has an `Application` namespace).